# Overriding Classes

Tags: java, oop, overriding

Lets say I have an application, x, which gets updated frequently and I need to modify this application with my package, y.

To get my package, y, running I modify one of the main classes in x  (is there any better way to do this?). I try to do as least edits as I can after this point. I do this because when x updates I can easily just copy in my modifications, add the call to y and away we go.

Now I've come across a problem I need to modify x's font renderer to use a nicer ttf font, this will entale modifying a whole class in x.

Is there any way to override a class thats in x in y without referencing y in x? I am thinking removing the whole class in x and replacing it with an extends but that would put extra strain on my head when x gets updated

Thanks in advance,
Jordan

Comment: Can you boil your code down to a short example? I have no clue what you are talking about right now...

Comment: I need to replace a class lets call this A with class B without referencing B in A @jlordo

Comment: I'm not sure `A` and `B` are any more clear than `x` and `y`.

Comment: There are numerous ways. We can't tell which ones are appropriate in your case without more context - and no, I won't describe them all and list their respective advantages.

Comment: I don't have access to a computer currently so I don't have any code samples currently

Answer (score 3):

You've described your problem in very general terms, so I can only answer generally. You should take a look at various structure patterns. The [facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) is designed to insulate code in one section of the program (package y) from changes in another (package x). For many changes to x, you simply need to update the facade and the nothing else in package y needs to change.

Related patterns are the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) and the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Given what you have described, I would suggest avoiding subclassing. It creates much more of a dependency than it sounds like you want.

Comment: Is there any way to override the class without initializing it first? I believe using a facade is very very close to what I need but it would require editing the base package a lot.

Comment: @JordanDoyle - The idea of the facade pattern is that you don't have to modify the backing code (package x) at all. (Or are you talking about modifying package y?) When you override a class, the base class constructor is always called (either explicitly or implicitly) as the first step in the execution of each constructor of the derived class. So, if I understand your question: no, there's no way to override a class without initializing it first. The facade pattern helps with that as well: you can defer initializing class members to whenever you need them initialized.

Comment: Package X, the original backing code, already has a facade and my code gets called later on in script execution but the way the backing code works is that it passes the class I need to override as a parameter to other classes so by the time my package is called its too late

Comment: @JordanDoyle - Ah. I thought this was a structural issue, but now you've introduced behavior considerations. I would suggest that you take a look at the [proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern). That might apply to this situation. Also take a look at some of the external links at the bottom of that page for ideas and insights.

Comment: I'll test this code tomorrow before commiting because I'm not at a computer at the moment. Thanks Ted :)

Answer (score 0):

you make something along the lines of this:

```
public class x{ some schtuff}
```

then you do this:

```
Public class y extends x { other stuff}
```

Hope this helps, my son had the same problem!